# Can you rewrite the NVL function?

Tags: sql, oracle, nvl

I'm using an NVL function in my WHERE clause like this.

```
... AND NVL(FIRST_DATE, SECOND_DATE) BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 7) and SYSDATE
```

What I'm doing is this: If FIRST_DATE is null then use the SECOND_DATE for comparison. The problem with this is that it prevents index usage on the column first_date or second_date. So I rewrote the condition into this:

```
... AND 
((FIRST_DATE BETWEEN (SYSDATE-7)  AND SYSDATE) 
OR 
(FIRST_DATE IS NULL AND SECOND_DATE BETWEEN (SYSDATE-7) AND SYSDATE))
```

I tested it by running it with different dates and it always returned the same results as with the NVL Function. But I want to make sure and check if I didn't miss any exceptions where the result may differ. Can anyone confirm that what I did is semantically equivalent to the NVL Function?

Comment: It is semantically equivalent.  But is it actually any faster?

Comment: You could create an index on NVL(FIRST_DATE, SECOND_DATE)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan If `FIRST_DATE` is null, the first condition automatically results into `FALSE`, which makes the `FIRST_DATE IS NOT NULL` redundant.

Comment: @TonyAndrews yes because it allows index usage without the need to create a function based index.

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't really the `NVL()` *per se*.  It is simply the complication of the `WHERE` clause.  Oracle supports indexes on expressions, so I would recommend a new index:

```
create index idx_t_dates on t(coalesce(first_date, second_date))
```

Then, if you use the same expression in the `where` clause, then the index should be used:

```
and coalesce(first_date, second_date) between sysdate - 7 and sysdate
```

I prefer `coalesce()`over `nvl()` because it is the standard function with the same functionality.

Comment: I was also thinking about creating a function based index but I didn't want to go that route, since it's once of our biggest tables.